# Canvas in SurfaceView - hardware acceleration

Tags: android, canvas, surfaceview, hardware-acceleration

I'm developing on ICS and trying to understand why a
Canvas.isHardwareAccelerated() will always return FALSE when using a
Canvas inside a SurfaceView.

I've tried a very basic example like this:
http://android-coding.blogspot.com/2011/05/drawing-on-surfaceview.html
Or this one: http://jmsliu.com/199/android-canvas-example.html

I even modified them to not have any canvas calls inside the draw loop
thinking that I might have got in some unsupported HW accel operations
for certain drawing calls.
I checked this list under "Unsupported Drawing Operations"
developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html
but I'm not doing any of that.

I am using the Force GPU rendering flag inside the Developer Options
together with 
inside the manifests, also I'm specifying minSDK/targetSDK >= 14.

The View.isHardwareAccelerated will return TRUE, while the
Canvas.isHardwareAccelerated will return always FALSE.

I've seen that Canvas.java has hard-codeded return false for isHardwareAccelerated(), while HardwareCanvas.java has return true. I guess for some reasons I'm not getting the HW path, why?

Can a Canvas inside a SurfaceView be HW accelerated?

Thanks

Answer (score 15):

A Canvas returned by `SurfaceView.lockCanvas()` cannot be hardware accelerated at the moment.

Comment: Is this still the case in JellyBean (4.2.1)?

Comment: @RomainGuy I found the hide api    `public Canvas lockHardwareCanvas()` but did not see where to use it, is it possible to use this method to get SurfaceView hardware accelerated?

Comment: Is this still the case in Lollipop??

Comment: How did you come to this conclusion?

Answer (score 5):

it seems that there is a new hide api method  `unlockHardwareCanvas` in `android.view.Surface`

and here is the example:

`http://androidxref.com/5.1.0_r1/xref/frameworks/base/tests/HwAccelerationTest/src/com/android/test/hwui/HardwareCanvasSurfaceViewActivity.java`

you can use relfecation in production environments.

Answer (score 1):

Have you stated in your android manifest, that your app wants to use hw acceleration?

This would be something like 
`<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" ...>`

Depending on what you want to do it might also be useful to only activate acceleration only for an activity or window, see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html for details.

Rudi

Comment: Yes I've stated <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" ...> in my manifest file, as a matter of fact, I can see the View HW accelerated but not the Canvas.

Comment: @AliAlNoaimi It must have worked on other views but not the SurfaceView. It's simply impossible as stated in another answer.