# React-native Android Systrace HTML is blank in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: android, google-chrome, ubuntu, react-native, systrace

I collected a trace of my React-Native based Android app using systrace.py util from Android SDK into an html file. When I open this html trace file in either Chrome 50.0.2661.86 (64 bit), or Firefox 45.0.2, I see blank screen and [a few JavaScript errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34z13.png) in Developer console. OS Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit OS.

However on my Windows machine a html trace is rendered correctly without errors in Chrome 49.0.2623.112.

Can anyone help me sort out this issue?

Comment: FWIW, on Win10 Chrome 50.0.2661.87 my systraces come up blank, while Ubuntu Chrome 49.0.2623.110 still works. I'm guessing Chrome broke.

Answer (score 13):

As a temporary workaround you can use the following approach:

- Save the .html dump file to disk
- Open tab in chrome `chrome://tracing`
- Load file in the tracing console

Comment: This fails with this message: 
```Error: Couldn't create an importer for the provided eventData.
    at Import.createImporter_ (chrome://tracing/tracing.js:1348:3342)
    at Import.createImports (chrome://tracing/tracing.js:1343:21)
    at Task.run (chrome://tracing/tracing.js:2062:13)
    at runAnother (chrome://tracing/tracing.js:2074:136)
    at runTask (chrome://tracing/tracing.js:2037:57)
    at processIdleWork (chrome://tracing/tracing.js:2043:116)
    at window.requestIdleCallback.timeout (chrome://tracing/tracing.js:2031:81)```

Answer (score 5):

In Chrome 49 there was a warning about Object.observe being deprecated.

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/02/chrome-49-deprecations?hl=en#objectobserve-is-deprecated

In Chrome 50 they finally removed it.

https://www.chromestatus.com/features/6147094632988672

Unfortunately, the systrace in Android platform-tools didn't follow-up. In the latest version (I tried Android SDK platform-tools 24 rc2) it is still generating html reports with Object.observe in it, so starting from Chrome 50 we're not able to open any of the reports.

I guess one way is to use a pre-50 release of Chrome.

Comment: In the Opera version 37.0 Systrace works fine for me.

Answer (score 5):

Simply adding

```js
<script src="https://rawgit.com/MaxArt2501/object-observe/master/dist/object-observe.min.js"></script>
```

to the head section of HTML document with trace makes it work in Chrome 50+

Comment: That worked for me. Link to the full project: https://github.com/MaxArt2501/object-observe

Comment: FWIW, I wouldn't recommend using GitHub for anything than an experiment. Fortunately, the polyfill is available here too: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/object-observe

Answer (score 0):

Systrace in Android SDK is outdated. You can use the systrace from the AOSP project:

```
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/chromium-trace
```