# How to address Android systrace generate html file errors?

Tags: android, systrace

I play with systrace follow the official guide

I can't select frame, the error in console shows like this.

[image]

I think it is a chrome compatible issues

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36865899/react-native-android-systrace-html-is-blank-in-ubuntu-14-04/

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be due to systrace itself. I had a similar problem and I updated my systrace according to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=57135.

You can try again after updating systrace:

```
cd $ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/chromium-trace/
mv systrace old-systrace
ln -s chromium-trace/catapult/systrace/systrace/ systrace
cd systrace
python update_systrace_trace_viewer.py
```

Sometimes the browser may also be the issue.